# Is there reliable method of ensuring crossdomain policy files have been retrieved for all Facebook image servers?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, crossdomain.xml

I've recently started putting together a Facebook Connect AS3 app and retrieving objects and images through the Graph API.

Running anywhere but locally, I receive security errors of the form:
    SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: xxxx cannot access http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/xxxx.jpg
    A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.

If I add a line of the form:
    Security.loadPolicyFile("ht_tp://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
-then I'm fine for that server, but it seems that there are any number of domains with the photos-[letter] format. I've added the one for each in the alphabet - which happily retrieves crossdomain files successfully - but it doesn't seem like a nice solution, and doesn't accommodate any new hosting setups Facebook <strike>may</strike> will implement in the future.

One thing I'd considered was retrieving the crossdomain policy file on a per image basis, capturing the domain from the image URL before making the image request. Unfortunately, at least via the Graph solution (and I haven't looked too closely at the others), their servers resolve the image url after the request is made, from something more generic like:
    ht_tps://graph.facebook.com/[objectId]/picture?type=small&access_token=[accessToken]

Has anyone found a more dependable means of ensuring that images can be retrieved without security sandbox violations? Or do Facebook maintain a definitive list that developers need to keep an eye on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the facebook crossdomains on the initial of your application as below;

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
```

and then whenever you want to load an image from facebook, set the checkPolicy flag to true using the Loader's LoaderContext as below;

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
context.checkPolicyFile = true;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadFacebookPhoto);
loader.load(new URLRequest(YOUR_FACEBOOK_PHOTO_URL),context);

private function onLoadFacebookPhoto(e:Event):void
{
    addChild(Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would guess that you'd want Flash to get the policy file on its own, rather than triggering it with `Security.loadPolicyFile`. Have you tried simply setting the `checkPolicyFile` flag for your Loader's `LoaderContext`?

Alternately, I believe that when you use `URLLoader` instead of `Loader`, Flash will request a policy file automatically, so you could try that as well. The tricky thing is that if you use `Loader`, Flash will let you display what you've loaded even without a crossdomain policy, so it doesn't load one unless you tell it to. When you use `URLLoader`, the load itself is not allowed unless there's a policy file, so Flash gets it automatically.